# Centering Carousel in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have a carousel and I am trying to center it to my page. I have tried text-align centering it, but it just won't work. Here is the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/MRhAD4HpQN) I'm not really sure why it's not working at all.

Comment: A carousel is not text. margin: 0 auto; or margin-left:auto and the same with the right.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in this bootply http://www.bootply.com/MRhAD4HpQN

You must add margin-left: auto; and margin-right: auto; in order to center it.